# Error while creating XML file

Tags: asp.net, xml, linq

I am trying to create a simple XML file, but I am getting the exception

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

at this part:

```
doc.Root.Add(persons);
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
 XDocument doc = new XDocument(new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", null));
    XElement persons = new XElement("Persons");
    XElement[] el ={new XElement("PersonInfo",new XAttribute("ID",1),
               new XElement("Name","ali"),
               new XElement("Phone","222222"))
               };

    persons.Add(el);
    doc.Add(persons);

    doc.Save("PhoneBook.xml", SaveOptions.None);
    Response.Write("ok");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just use:

```
doc.Add(persons);
```

Then you will get this XML:

```
<Persons>
  <PersonInfo ID="1">
    <Name>ali</Name>
    <Phone>222222</Phone>
  </PersonInfo>
</Persons>
```

An empty `XDocument` has no `Root`. That's why you get a `NullReferenceException` when you try to access it.

Comment: I have changed my code as you suggested I dont get exception but there is no xml file anywhere.not crerated

Comment: That might be caused by a number of reasons. Does your app have write permission for the destination directory? I'm running this code from a simple console application. ASP.NET applications need more security settings to save files.

Comment: but this code run last night without problem or any permission  .i just wanted to practice one more time and now not working

Comment: you are right.It Worked this way xdoc.Save(Server.MapPath("MYXML.XML"), SaveOptions.None);

but I am wondering What changed in one day.Because as i said code run last night without any problems.I am just wondering